# Tensorflow installation error: not a supported wheel on this platform - Python 3.6.7 - pip 20.0.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I know this question has been asked a couple of times but I can't seem to find a proper answer. I am trying to install tensorflow on my Windows x64 machine but keep on getting the error: *ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.*

I work with :
- Python 3.6.7
- pip 20.0.2
- virtualenv 20.0.4

after activating the virtualenv:
.\venv\Scripts\activate

I try **pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl**

for which I get: **ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

If anyone has ran on these issues, should I upgrade / downgrade any of these versions of Python, pip or virtualenv ?

Comment: Your Python is perhaps 32-bit (a common mistake). Install 64-bit Python and recreate virtual environment(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you have conda installed, I can help you.

Start with conda base shell (start menu -> Anaconda -> Anaconda prompt).

1) create environment

```
conda create --name tensorflow21_env
```

2) activate environment

```
conda activate tensorflow21_env
```

3) install

1. `conda install python=3.7`
2. `pip install tensorflow-cpu  #install tensorflow=2.1.0;`

I worked with 
Python 3.7.6 and pip 20.0.2.

pip installed package:

```
tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I hope it helps.